# I'm using xtag in selenium but can't able to clk on link. My html code contains href and onclick tags both

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

i'm new user of selenium and using driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='main']/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[3]/a")).click();but it didn't clk on link.

```html
<section id="main" class="margintopless-6" role="main">
<div class="row clearfix mainsection">
<div class="minheight500">
<!-- Marquee Code-->
<div class="clear marquee">
<div class="center mrg50T mrg25B">
<div class="clear margin-bottom-20"/>
<div>
<!--MArquee Code-->
<div class="col-md-2"/>
<div class="col-md-4 pad45R mrg15B">
<div class="homelinks whitebg">
<div class="center">
<ul class="pad15TLR">
<li>
<li>
<li>
<a onclick="fetchJob(1);" href="#">
</li>
<li/>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Is all the values are visible and whats the err msg you are getting?

Comment: Please post your stacktrace? Is there any exception/error on clicking it?

Comment: Hi @santhoshkumar stack trace is org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"main"}

Comment: If possible can you give me the URL and the element that you need to click?

Comment: @santhoshkumar can't give u url as it's secure url on which i'm working.plz help me with other method

Comment: can you give the complete HTML highlighting the element that needs to identified

Comment: <div class="wrapper1">
<div id="txt"/>
<section id="main" class="margintopless-6" role="main">
<div class="row clearfix mainsection">
<div class="minheight500">
<!-- Marquee Code-->
<div class="clear marquee">
<div class="center mrg50T mrg25B">
<div class="clear margin-bottom-20"/>
<div>

Comment: @santhoshkumar <!--MArquee Code-->
<div class="col-md-2"/>
<div class="col-md-4 pad45R mrg15B">
<div class="homelinks whitebg">
<div class="center">
<ul class="pad15TLR">
<li>
<li>
<li>
<a onclick="fetchJob(1);" href="#">
</li>
<li/>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>

Comment: driver.findElement(by.xpath("//li/a")).click();

Comment: @santhoshkumar there is another href with same link text which is 
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
<div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
<div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2" class="collapse navbar-collapse topnav">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav secondnav">
<li id="SubmodLI_112" class="active">
<li id="SubmodLI_113">
<a onclick="funSubModuleClick('../..//loadOnboardInboxModule.do','111','113','Inbox','-1','113')" href="#">Inbox</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</header>
</div>
so how can i select that specific link??

Comment: can you try with this->//ul[@class='pad15TLR']/li/li/li/a

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your question and the answer.

1. You are not using xtag, you are using Xpath.
2. The xpath which you have used is incorrect, it should be:

**.//*[@id='main']//div[@class='homelinks whitebg']//ul/li[3]/a**

If you are a beginner, please use firepath for computing the XPath.

I can see that your HTML contains **href** and **onclick** event handler.
**href** is # that means, it will not take you to any separate link. I don't see any text with your anchor tag. There should be a link text.

Comment: there's a txt 
<div class="homelinks whitebg">
<div class="center">
<ul class="pad15TLR">
<li>
<li>
<li>
<a onclick="fetchJob(1);" href="#">
Inbox 
<span class="red"/>
</a>
</li>
<li/>
but in html there is another link with same text
<div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2" class="collapse navbar-collapse topnav">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav secondnav">
<li id="SubmodLI_112" class="active">
<li id="SubmodLI_113">
<a onclick="funSubModuleClick('../..//loadOnboardInboxModule.do','111','113','Inbox','-1','113')" href="#">Inbox</a>
</li>

Comment: i used your suggestion but it's not working as well. plz help

Comment: Can you check whether this element is under iframe? If it is, you have to switch to iframe first. There shouldn't be any problem in clicking the element if it is not in iframe.

Comment: yes it's under iframe#bodyframe. so how could i resolve issue now??

Comment: driver.switchTo().frame("id of the iframe");